# Azure CDN metrics for monitoring

Tags: metrics, azure-cdn

I have a CDN in Azure and I want to generate a graph in a dashboard or workbook where I can display the number of requests made to the CDN and in particular the number of failed requests (for example, when a request failed because this is a wrong resource URL or the asset is not anymore in the CDN).
Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with Azure Diagnostics settings.
[image]

Under Logs you have option to setup your custom metrics depending on the query/condition.
[image]

Here are some of the conditions you can set for measuring the metrics,

1. Top 10 URL request count
2. Resuest per hour
3. Top 10 client IPs and http versions
4. 4XX error rate by URL.

**Ref:** https://github.com/microsoft/AzureMonitorCommunity/tree/master/Azure%20Services/CDN%20profiles